# Using the Null template in a sql_create statement MySQL++ properly

Tags: mysql, mysql++

According to the documentation [here](https://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/tutorial.html#sql-null) and [here](https://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/ssqls.html#sql_create), I should be able to use a Null template and specify that a null is equal to zero like so...

```
sql_create_1(myResults, 1, 0, mysqlpp::Null<mysqlpp::sql_int, mysqlpp::NullIsZero>, my_column);
```

This does not compile though.  I get the following compiler error...

> error: macro "sql_create_1" passed 6 arguments, but takes just 5
>    sql_create_1(myResults, 1, 0, mysqlpp::Null, my_column);

If I remove the "mysqlpp::NullIsZero" as the 2nd argument of the template (defaults to NullIsNull) as follows...

```
sql_create_1(myResults, 1, 0, mysqlpp::Null<mysqlpp::sql_int>, my_column);
```

All is well.